# How to change a Text View font size by using OnTouchListener?

Tags: android, font-size, ontouchlistener

I have a text view and i want to do this : when i tap on text view the font size change to 27 and i can scroll and read the text in this font size(27), but whenever i tap again, the font size back to 15, i used this code but when i scroll and i want to read the text,immediately the font change to 15 just by scrolling, how can i fix it? here is the code :

```
content.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()){

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    content.setTextSize(27);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    content.setTextSize(15);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @user8035311 no, it is just a text view and get its content from a SQLite db.

Comment: @user8035311 you mean maybe I forgot to use " break; " in my code? no,i'm sure, i used my code exactly the same as i wrote it in my question.

Comment: @user8035311 no i didn't check it out cause i didn't have any error,can you explain more? if generating ACTION_DOWN right after ACTION_UP is wrong so what i should write in between?

Comment: as you said i did it right now, but it doesn't work : content.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ @Override  public void onClick(View v){if (content.getTextSize()==15){ content.setTextSize(27)} else if((content.getTextSize()==27){ content.setTextSize(15)}}});

Comment: @user8035311 read the comment above

Comment: @user8035311 yes you are right,but at first i set text size in 15 but again that does not work, it is just the same as TouchListener, when you tap it become bigger but after that u can not change it back by tapping again